# Ubuntu kvm not working with gpu passthrough

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kvm, qemu, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed qemu and kvm on arch linux!  Then I installed Ubuntu in the qxl display and everything works fine, but when ubuntu is started with the pci devices it just shows some green line and then it turns of the display. 
I used the same config as for my windows vm, but there the gpu works perfectly... 
May I have to install the nvidia drivers for Ubuntu? 
I hope you can help me and thank you